# How to print a list of xts objects into a single time series plot?

Tags: r, plot, xts

I would like to plot a superposition of a long list of time series objects.

```
class(ts.l)
# [1] "list"
class(ts.l[[1]])
# [1] "xts" "zoo"
```

I know that `ts.plot()` can do that. So, when I invoke the command `ts.plot(as.ts(ts.l[[1]]), as.ts(ts.l[[2]]), as.ts(ts.l[[2]]))` it works.

But I don't know how to give the whole list to `ts.plot()` all at once. The following code lines both do not work:

```
ts.plot(unlist(sapply(ts.l, as.ts)))
```

This seems to merge the time series into a single series.

```
ts.plot(sapply(ts.l, as.ts))
```

Produces an error message

> Object cannot be coerced to type double

So, does anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: `ts.plot(sapply(ts.l, as.ts))` seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new `plot.xts` in the [development version of xts on GitHub](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts) handles multi-column xts objects. For example:

```
require(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
# create list of xts objects
ts.l <- as.list(as.xts(sample_matrix))
# merge xts list into one object
ts.o <- do.call(merge, ts.l)
plot(ts.o)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So, this will not work with the CRAN xts package?

Comment: In my case I do not have time series with multivariate features, but an array (i.e. a list) of several univariate time series objects.

Comment: @user1881788: No, this will not work with the current xts version on CRAN. If you want to plot several univariate series on the same coordinates, the time index of each series must be aligned, so you effectively *do* have a time series with multivariate features. My example was simply illustrative, since you did not provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I wanted! Great ;)

Comment: But just in general I would like to know how to feed a list into a function that expects a (...) argument. Like I wrote in the beginning `ts.plot(as.ts(ts.l[[1]]), as.ts(ts.l[[2]]), as.ts(ts.l[[2]]))` works, but `ts.plot(unlist(sapply(ts.l, as.ts)))` does not. Best!

Comment: @user1881788: you can use `do.call` to construct the call. Using `ts.l` from my example: `do.call(ts.plot, lapply(ts.l,as.ts))`.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following function to transform `xts` objects into a format that `ggplot2` can work with:

```
xts_to_dataframe = function(..., xts_ids) {
  xts_list = list(...)
  all_include_stop_time = all(sapply(xts_list, function(x) return(!is.null(attr(x, 'stop_timestamps')))))
  names_null = sapply(xts_list, function(x) is.null(names(x)))
  if (any(names_null)) stop('Some xts objects do not have a valid `names` attribute.')
  data_frame_list = lapply(xts_list, function(xts_obj) {
    xts_vars = lapply(names(xts_obj), function(xts_variable) {
      output = data.frame(timestamps = index(xts_obj[,xts_variable]), 
                          values = as.vector(xts_obj[,xts_variable]))
      if (all_include_stop_time) {
        output = cbind(output, stop_timestamps = attr(xts_obj, 'stop_timestamps'))
      }   
      return(output)
    })  
    combined_data_frame = do.call('rbind', xts_vars)
    rownames(combined_data_frame) = NULL
    combined_data_frame[['variable']] = rep(names(xts_obj), sapply(xts_vars, nrow))
    return(combined_data_frame)
  })  
  combined_data_frame_list = do.call('rbind', data_frame_list)
  if (missing(xts_ids)) xts_ids = seq_along(data_frame_list)
  combined_data_frame_list[['xts_obj_id']] = rep(xts_ids, sapply(data_frame_list, nrow))
  return(combined_data_frame_list)
}
```

Just feed it a bunch of `xts` objects, and the resulting `data.frame` can be plotted using `ggplot2`. For example:

```
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = timestamps, y = values, color = xts_obj_id)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts. However, how should I call this function? `df <- xts_to_dataframe(ts.l, names(ts.l))` does not work.

Comment: Essentially, my xts objects do not have name attributes. `names(ts.l[[1]])` is equal to NULL. However, `names(ts.l)` is defined, of course.

Comment: Because of the `...` you need to explicitly name the final argument. You can also simply omit it like this: `df <- xts_to_dataframe(ts.l)`.

Comment: Omitting also gives an error: "incorrect number of dimensions". This is probably because I do not have "multiple time series objects" but only univariate ones. I guess I need to do something like `sapply(ts.l, function(x) names(x) <- "var_name")` or so!?

Comment: Have you tried using `zoo::autoplot.zoo` or `zoo::fortify.zoo`? I'm not familiar with either function, but it appears they should do something very similar to what your function does.  They should work with xts objects, since xts extends zoo.